# Passing objects to methods jcreator

Tags: object, methods

```
public static void battleWithLoin( Object spartan1, Object spartanLion){
    System.out.println( spartan1.spartanHealth + " Versus " + spartanLion.spartanHealth);

}
```

when I run compiler gets cant find symbol. I believe its talking about the .spartanHealth. Why cant this method access the Spartan object variables?

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler is checking the class `Object` for the field `spartanHealth`.
Change the types of the parameters to `Spartan` since that's the class with the `spartanHealth` field.

Since the compiler doesn't run your code, it has know way of knowing those Objects are actually Spartans.  If you must leave the parameters the way they are, then you have to cast the variables to let the compiler know.

```
((Spartan) spartan1).spartanHealth
```